# Pull random unique samples within sorted categories in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, random, command-line

I have a large unsorted CSV file (>4M records). Each record has a category, which is described in the first three columns. The rest of the record is address data which may or may not be unique.

```
A, 1, c, address1  # the category for this record is A1t
A, 1, c, address2
C, 3, e, address3  # the category for this record is C3e
B, 2, a, address4
```

I would like to pull a random sample of unique records within each category (so 5 unique records in category `A1t`, 5 unique records from `C3e`, etc.). I put together a partial solution using `sort`. However, it only pulls one non-random record in each category:

```
sort -u -t, -k1,3
```

Is there a way to pull several random sample records within each category?

I think there must be a way to do this by using a combination of pipes, `uniq`, `awk` or `shuf`, but haven't been able to figure it out. I would prefer a command-line solution since I'm interested in knowing if this is possible using only bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the use of `sort -R` in the [answer by jm666](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089769/1566221). This is a GNU extension to `sort`, so it may not work on non-Gnu systems.

Here, we use sort to sort the entire file once, with the non-category fields sorted in a random order. Since the category fields are the primary key, the result is in category order with random order of the following fields.

From there, we need to find the first five entries in each category. There are probably hackier ways to do this, but I went with a simple `awk` program.

```
sort -ut, -k1,3 -k4R "$csvfile" | awk -F, 'a!=$1$2$3{a=$1$2$3;n=0}++n<=5'
```

If your `sort` doesn't randomise, then the random sample can be extracted with `awk`:

```
# Warning! Only slightly tested :)
sort -ut, "$csvfile" | awk -F, '
      function sample(){
        for(;n>5;--n)v[int(n*rand())+1]=v[n];
        for(;n;--n)print v[n]
      }
      a!=$1$2$3{a=$1$2$3;sample()}
      {v[++n]=$0}
      END      {sample()}'
```

It would also be possible to keep all the entries in awk to avoid the sort, but that's likely to be a lot slower and it will use an exorbitant amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was possible to use the `-R` option on a specific row. The awk snippet is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: Like @rici mentioned, `sort` with the `-R` option is not available on non-GNU systems like mac OS X. I downloaded `coreutils` (via homebrew, `brew install coreutils`), which has a `gsort` command equivalent to GNU `sort` and includes the `-R` option.

Comment: @gunnar: `sort -k4R` means sort the fields from 4 to the end of the line using a randomized hash. So it's not exactly a single column. It was important to use a delimited first key (`-k1,3` means from field 1 to the end of field 3). If you want a sort key to be a single column, you need to write the column number twice: `-k1,1` for example.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right - simple, not very effective bash solution

```
csvfile="./ca.txt"
while read -r cat
do
    grep "^$cat," "$csvfile" | sort -uR | head -5
done < <(cut -d, -f1-3 < "$csvfile" |sort -u)
```

decomposition

- `cut -d, -f1-3 < "$csvfile"` - filter out all "categories" (first 3 fields)
- `sort -u` - get sorted **unique** categories
- for each unique category (`while read...`)
- `grep "^$cat" "$csvfile"` find all lines from this category
- `sort -uR` - sort them randomly by hash (note, the duplicates has the same hash, take unique)
- `head -5` print the first 5 records (from the randomly sorted list)