# Philosophical Sorting Idea

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sequence

Does sorting an array mean introducing in it order, or is it recovering order that is inherent in a sequence of numbers?

This is an idea that was presented in some algorithm analysis materials I was reading online and it made me wonder which was true. I can think of arguments for both sides, but is there any answer that is more "correct" than another?

Comment: Any reference on what you read ?

Comment: It all depends on the criterium you are using to order that array. Because of that, there is not a "inherent" sequence of number. For instance, say that you want to sort your array according to their squares (from min to max) but you have negative numbers. So `a=[-3 -1 0 1 2 3]` you would say it is ordered? If you order how I said: `a_sorted=[0 1 -1 2 -2 3]` (or `a=[0 -1 1 -2 2 3]`.  Sorting means that you are giving any cost to the elements and therefore you place those elements with that cost monotonically increasing (or decreasing).

Comment: if by `order` one would mean amount of information (or reverse of amount of entropy), then sorting is actually destroying the ordinal information - as an ordered array can be reduced to a set (allowing duplicated values) and a sorting function, while unsorted array has to contain information about ordinal position of each element..

Comment: @JaviV I have two issues with that you wrote: First, for numbers there *is* an "inherent" order, the canonical/natural (pun not intended) order `<`. Second, explaining sorted order as "monotonically increasing w.r.t. some cost" is not general enough (it presumes a concept of numbers, whereas the usual and more fundamental definition is simply in terms of an order *relation*).

Comment: @delnan totally agree with you. However, the most general sorting does not always sort according to the inherent number ordering. Anyway, I think you are saying the same as me but more formally :)

Comment: @JaviV all you need is the original array and the sorting function, there is no more information in the sorted array. already sorted stuff might just be easier to manipulate in some applications, but I can imagine a sorted `generator` to work as well as an array

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought experiment. [Note 1]

Suppose I have a very large file of unsorted lines, some of which are duplicated. I want a random sample of the unique values of the lines. And I have available a generalized sort function.

Now, I could sort the file, remove the duplicates, and then take a random sample. But that seems to be a bit more work than I really need.

Instead, what if I sort the file based on a sort key which is a randomly-selected hash function of each line? (This idea isn't mine, by the way. It's actually implemented by GNU sort.) Now, I just need to remove duplicates until I complete the size of my sample.

That might not be the optimal solution to my problem, but it's a reasonable solution which takes some advantage of existing tools. But that's not the point with respect to this question: The point is that there is no conceivable way you can say that the sort operation being done by this algorithm is an inherent property of the values; in fact, it is simply one of a very large (though finite) number of possible similar sort operations, each of which (probably) yields a different order.

---

**Notes:**

1. Actually, it's not a thought experiment; it's based on [a question elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089652/pull-random-unique-samples-within-sorted-categories-in-bash/26090099#26090099), but we can think of it as a thought experiment :)

Comment: [technically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting), I would not consider the choosing of hash function as part of the sorting, but as a separate prior step. then the sort itself is pretty deterministic and repeatable

Comment: @Aprillion: I hope I was clear that the hash function is randomly selected once for the entire sort. But the sort doesn't reveal any property of the data. You could say that it reveals a property of the (ephemeral) transformation of the data, but you can equally well say that the comparison function used is a parameter to the sortation algorithm rather than being inherent to the data. The latter is my position. Sorting works provided that the comparison function used is consistent, complete, antisymmetric and transitive. But within those constraints, anything can be used.

Comment: you were clear on that. but `it will be different each time, depending on the randomly-selected hash function` statement can be reduced to `it will be different if you choose a different sorting function each time` - which is kind of obvious

Comment: @Aprillion: Ok, tried an edit.

Comment: ah, i believe there is an infinite number of possible sort operations that yield the same order `{a<b, a*2<b*2, ...}` and/or different order. but +1 as i agree that sorting is not inherent to anything :)

Comment: @Aprillion: there are an infinite number of sorting functions but a finite number of sorting functions of the form I describe, although the finity is implicit since I didn't describe the algorithm used to select a random hash-function. The ones I had in mind are parameterized by a finite-length string which can be randomly selected. I'm not sure that level of detail is necessary but I might add it later.